# Copying hierarchy in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have the following model:

[image]

And I want the user to be able to duplicate a drawing so he has a new one with all the triangles, edges and vertex than the original.

At first I thought I would go trough all attributes (copying there values) and relationships (creating new entities). Bus as you can see there are some recursive relationships and I don't think that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do it in two steps:

First create the new objects, copying the attribute values. 
In this step, also store, e.g in a `NSMutableDictionary` the mapping from original object to copied object: for each object that you copy do `[targetObjects setObject:copiedObject forKey:[originalObject objectID]]`. 
(You have to use `objectID` because `NSManagedObjects` can not be used as dictionary keys.

You can then recreate the relationships in a second step using the information from the original relationships and from the `targetObjects` dictionary.